# :request_timeout with MachineGun when upgrading to otp 23

Tags: erlang, elixir

When we upgraded to elixir 1.10.3-otp-23, all requests through MachineGun started coming back with :request_timeout. Is there something that changed in OTP 23 that might be causing this issue?

This is our current MachineGun version: `{:machine_gun, "~> 0.1.6"}`, which did not change with the upgrade.

```
headers = [{"Content-type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8"}, {"Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate"}]

opts = %{
  ssl: [{:versions, [:"tlsv1.2"]}]
}

MachineGun.post(endpoint, request_xml, headers, opts)
```

Comment: OTP23 has [completely removed support for `ssl3`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/releases) but added `tlsv1.3`. This should not affect your case since you were using `tlsv1.2`, but I’d start with upgrading to `tlsv1.3` _and_ enabling trace/debug for HTTP calls.